# Lifting dg-algebras to characteristic zero

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, differential-graded-algebras, higher-algebra

For a smooth algebra $A$ over a finite field $k$, by a Theorem R. Elkik, there always exists a lift to characteristic zero (apologies for the previous mistake). My question is how the analogous situation is in the world of dg-algebras. Is the analgous result true for smooth dg-algebras over a finite field to characteristic zero? I know dg-algebras in positive characteristic are not exaclty the best behaved objects, so maybe it would be better to switch context?

Comment: Be careful: the obstruction is only for lifting to $W_2(k)$, or if the whole $H^2(X,T_X)$ vanishes inductively to a *formal* lift over $W(k)$. The fact that smooth affines lift as *schemes* is a nontrivial theorem due to Elkik.

Comment: Ohhh, @R.vanDobbendeBruyn thanks, I'll rectify it!

Comment: Supplementing the comment of @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, the lift exists for any surjection of rings, not only henselian ones like $W(k)\to k$: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07M8

Comment: Are you thinking about associative or commutative dg algebras? (the remark about them being non well-behaved make me suggest it's the latter). An example of a non-liftable (even over $W_2(k)$) smooth associative dg algebra can be constructed as follows: take a smooth projective variety $X$ of dimension $<p$ such that the Hodge-to-de Rham spectral sequence of $X$ does not degenerate (in particular, $X$ is not liftable to $W_2(k)$) and let $A$ be a dg algebra such that $D^b(X)=A-Mod$ (one can construct such $A$ as the derived endomorphisms of a generator of $D^b(X)$).

Comment: If $A$ was liftable to $W_2(k)$ then the non-commutative Hodge-to-de Rham spectral sequence for $A$ would degenerate, but that would imply, by the degeneration of the HKR spectral sequence for $X$, that the Hodge-to-de Rham spectral sequence of $X$ degenerates as well, contradicting our assumption.